# Delete specific pattern Unix

Tags: sed, pattern-matching

I have a string that look like this:

```
Root;rootrank;Bacteria;domain;"Actinobacteria";phylum;Actinobacteria;class;Acidimicrobidae;subclass;Acidimicrobiales;order;"Acidimicrobineae";suborder;Acidimicrobiaceae;family;Acidimicrobium;genus
```

and I want to delete this

```
root; rootrank; domain; phylum; class; subclass;order;suborder;family;genus
```

but I'm struggling a lot with sed

Comment: Can you format the original line and the line that you want to get after the deletion as code using the "{}" delimiters?

Comment: Could you add what you tried with `sed` that is not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
printf "%s\n" \
  "Root;rootrank;Bacteria;domain;"Actinobacteria";phylum;Actinobacteria;class;Acidimicrobidae;subclass;Acidimicrobiales;order;"Acidimicrobineae";suborder;Acidimicrobiaceae;family;Acidimicrobium;genus" \
  | sed -e 's/Root;//' \
        -e 's/rootrank;//' \
        -e 's/domain;//' \
        -e 's/phylum;//' \
        -e 's/class;//' \
        -e 's/subclass;//' \
        -e 's/order;//' \
        -e 's/suborder;//' \
        -e 's/family;//' \
        -e 's/genus//'
```

Gives you:

```
Bacteria;Actinobacteria;Actinobacteria;Acidimicrobidae;Acidimicrobiales;Acidimicrobineae;Acidimicrobiaceae;Acidimicrobium;
```

You can chain several `sed` commands togeather.  `-e 's/foo/bar/'` means "substitute `foo` with `bar`" but in our case we simply substituted with nothing (so we effectively just deleted `foo`).